# Get User health data from Microsoft Health Cloud API in iOS

Tags: ios, rest, microsoft-band

Is there any way that i can access health data from Microsoft Health Cloud in my iOS App.Are there any restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Microsoft Health Cloud API is a web service, so it can be used by any client capable of HTTP requests.  You'll need to manage the OAuth-based authentication within your iOS application (e.g. by hosting a web view that allows the user to sign-in with their Microsoft Account) but, after that point, it's just plain REST.

See the [Getting Started documentation](http://developer.microsofthealth.com/Content/docs/MS%20Health%20API%20Getting%20Started.pdf) for more details about authentication and API.

Comment: @Phill Hoff Is there any way i can retrieve day by day calories burned for a period of 1 week?as i visited the api the option is to retrieve total calories burned for a week and does'nt have the day to day details.

Comment: @Sulabh: You can request [daily summaries](http://developer.microsofthealth.com/cloudAPI/Explorer#!/Summaries/Summaries_Get). The data returned includes calories burned per day.